# Android find array index value of a partial match

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist, indexof

I'm looking for a way to find the index position of a partial match in Java (Android).

Let's say my Array is:

```
String ips[] = {"10.185.98.111", "192.168.0.13", "Some random IPV6 address"};
```

I'd like to be able to something like `ips[].indexOf("192")` and this return "1" rather than "-1".

Is this possible?

Comment: So `ips[0].indexOf("192")` returns -1 for you there?

Comment: @Obversity I hope so, seeing that "10.185.98.111" doesn't have 192

Comment: Are you trying to get the index of the given substring in a String, or the index in a String array of the String that contains the given substring? That is, when you say you'd like it to return "1", is that because the String at position 1 in the array contains "192"?

Comment: @gtgaxiola I probably should have known better than to visit StackOverflow at 6:15 in the morning after not having slept, especially when I've been making typos all day.

Comment: @Obversity Hello from the other side of the world then! Here is just 2:45 in the afternoon :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do your own function such as:

```
public int getElementThatContains(String[] ips, String key) {
    for (int i = 0; i < ips.length; i++) {
        if (ips[i].indexOf(key) >= 0) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Observe that the ordering of your `list` will determine which ip you'll get.
If you have two elements with `192` whichever is closer to the beginning will get selected.

Also you may change:

```
if (ips[i].indexOf(key) >= 0) {
    return i;
}
```

To different kind of matches such as:

```
ips[i].contains(key)
ips[i].startsWith(key)
ips[i].endsWith(key)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public void specialIndexOF(List<String> ips){
        int index=0;
            for(String s:ips){
        if(s.contains(search)){
        return index;
        }
        index++;
            }
    return -1;
        }
```